# My navbar has a gap when it scrolls and i want it to stick to the top

Tags: html, css, navbar, blogger

I recently tried to change my nav bar so it had a drop down options but it didn't work. However, I now have a little symbol at the top of my nav bar and when I scroll down the page there is a space between the nav bar and the top of the page. I just want my navbar to stick to the top of the page whilst scrolling.

I have no idea how to change it.

Here's my blog; https://bellisssimo.blogspot.co.uk/

This is what I want it to be like: http://www.naomivictoria.co.uk/

I have been trying to use CSS and HTML but I don't understand at all!!

Comment: inspect element and see the `[` character in the html of your block creating the gap

Answer (score 0):

There's a strange "[" after your body starting tag when you remove it the page works great and as expected

check your page using inspect element to understand more

Comment: where do I remove it?

Comment: It is just an un used character that has no use and ruins your mind design also oftenly this  "[" has no use and is writtin by mistake from you

Comment: I went onto inspect and I'm trying to delete it and it goes but when I refresh it's back again. How do I save changes?

Comment: Inspect elemnt doesnt save its edits ot just shows you direct preview of code if you want to save changes you have to edit the files themeselves hosted on the server

Comment: Or php pageI mean the actuall htm

Answer (score 0):

Please remove "line-height" from your blog's html body

and after that give "top:0;" property to your navigation bar

apply below changes and enjoy...

body{ line-height:0; }

#navigation{ top: 0; }

Comment: thank you! I just added this to my blog CSS and it worked.

Comment: oh wait actually it works but then the text on my blog for blog posts and everything else goes fuzzy and there's double that overlaps. :(

Comment: please add "text-shadow: none;"  property where your text is blurred and if there is an issue with "line-height" that you removed from body.....please add is works normally with fix navigation  and also remove " ] " from your blog's body element.....sometimes it generate issues with responsive......

Comment: where do i find all of this that you talking about? where do i put text shadow? where do i put line-height where do i remove ]

Comment: put "text-shadow: none" where your text is blur......and put line-height in your body element......and rest one that "]"  that is remove from body.....